# Need help explain about normal vector SceneKit

Tags: ios, vector, opengl-es, scenekit

I follow this article to create a custom `SCNGeometry`

http://ronnqvi.st/custom-scenekit-geometry/

I see it need normal vector for every vertex. I also see the document here 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNGeometrySource_Class/index.html

In my knowledge, I think 3 vertices identify one plane and one plane need only 1 normal vector. So each 3 vertices we need 1 normal vector. Then it will decrease data and calculations

Can anybody help me explain it? or may I confused something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

specifying normals at the vertex level (instead of face level) leads to better looking models. For instance spheres can be modelled with a decent number of vertices and will look perfectly round when shaded. This is because the normal at each point is the mathematically correct normal. If you took the face normal, then you could easily see these faces with a standard shading.